How many functions for Maybe a -> Maybe a?
In Thinking Functionally with Haskell (p 45), Richard Bird says there are six functions with type Maybe a -> Maybe a, though he only names five.

Applied to Nothing the function can only return Nothing or undefined.
Applied to Just x the function can only return Nothing or Just x or
undefined. The point is that we know absolutely nothing about the
underlying type, so no new values can be invented. That makes six
possible functions in all.

I count seven:
first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh :: Maybe a -> Maybe a

first (Just x) = Just x
second (Just x) = Nothing
third (Just x) = undefined
fourth Nothing = Nothing
fifth Nothing = undefined
sixth undefined = Nothing
seventh undefined = undefined

A related puzzle is that when I try to put three of these definitions under a single function, I get a compilation error "Pattern match is redundant." Removing any of the three lines causes it to disappear
foo :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
foo (Just x) = Nothing
foo Nothing = undefined
foo undefined = Nothing


You need to multiply 2*3, not add. This is because you can set the outputs for Just x and Nothing separately.

I don't quite understand your code sample, but from your "he only names 5" comment I think you're getting confused and essentially adding when you should be multiplying (as far as counting functions is concerned, anyway). A function of the given type needs to be defined on both Just x and Nothing, and as your source says, there are only 3 possibilities for the output of one of these, and 2 for the other - so the total number of such functions is 2*3=6.

The paragraph you quoted mentions 2 choices for input Nothing and 3 choices for input Just x. So in total we have 3*2=6 ways to define a function defined on the (non-bottom) values of type Maybe a. Also note that there is no way to match undefined as you attempt to do: foo undefined = Nothing actually means foo y = Nothing for all y. (The compiler warns with the "Pattern match is redundant." message).

I think the function can also return Just undefined in both cases, so the total number of functions is 3*4 = 12.

maybe <$> [Nothing, undefined] <*> [Just, const Nothing, undefined] :: [Maybe a -> Maybe a] is a list of the six possible functions.

You cannot pattern match on undefined. So, when you write foo undefined = ... you are naming the argument undefined, which is completely unrelated to the builtin undefined.

Your functions are not fully specified -- each time they take only one case. This means that the case that is not covered, errors.
so essentially if you write:
first (Just x) = Just x
it is:
first (Just x) = Just x
first _ = error "case not covered"
You thus need to cover the two cases combined: Just x, or Nothing and thus multiply the possibilities of each case.
Another problem is that undefined in sixth undefined = Nothing does not check if the item is undefined: it is just a variable named undefined. So it is equivalent to sixth x = Nothing.
So that leaves us essentially with three options for Just x: Just x, Nothing and undefined/error, and two options for Nothing: Nothing and undefined, so:
first (Just x) = Just x
first Nothing = Nothing

second (Just x) = Just x
second Nothing = undefined

third (Just x) = Nothing
third Nothing = Nothing

fourth (Just x) = Nothing
fourth Nothing = undefined

fifth (Just x) = undefined
fifth Nothing = Nothing

sixth (Just x) = undefined
sixth Nothing = undefined
These are however not all the options: you can also return Just undefined (or Just (error "<undefined>")) for any of the two cases. I leave listing these as an exercise.

Correct, but note that your 6 functions are not total either since undefined is used. The figure 2*3=6 appears to count the "semi"-total functions (result is either bottom or totally defined) defined on total inputs, which can be a little weird. If I had to count the functions, I'd rule out bottoms completely, or allow them everywhere.

If we consider undefined as a possible argument, f x = Nothing is another definition that's distinct from f (Just x) = Nothing; f Nothing = Nothing.

I know what Bird was going for, but this assertion is just weird:

That makes six possible functions in all.

If you pretend to be in a strict, total language for a moment, there are only two possible functions with type Maybe a -> Maybe a: id and const Nothing.
When you remember Haskell is non-strict and not total, you get one additional slightly-interesting implementation:
foo :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
foo Nothing = Nothing
foo (Just _) = Nothing

This is like const Nothing, except it causes its argument to be evaluated when its result is, though it's not entirely clear what sort of case you'd want this in. Since id is already strict in this way, there's only that one additional interesting implementation.
So there are three implementations of that type that actually make sense to write. That's less than the six Bird claims, but the quote does indicate Bird was also considering returning nonsense bottoms. But if you start counting those, there are a lot more than six possible functions. (I'm going to do the standard thing and assume all bottoms are indistinguishable. That's not actually true, but for my purposes it's good enough. I'm also going to rule out any sort of implementation that does nonsense extra work only observable in the amount of time it takes the function to execute.)
First off, let's consider case splitting. Nothing can be mapped to three different results:
Nothing -> Nothing
Nothing -> Just undefined
Nothing -> undefined

and Just x can be mapped to seven:
Just x -> Nothing
Just x -> x `seq` Nothing
Just x -> Just x
Just x -> x `seq` Just x
Just x -> Just undefined
Just x -> x `seq` Just undefined
Just x -> undefined

Note that since I've declared I'm not going to distinguish between bottoms, Just x -> x `seq` undefined isn't an important implementation. If you actually were going to distinguish between them, that'd be worth note as well. Though if that's really what you need, you would also need to use pseq instead of seq so that you would be assured what order they would be evaluated in. Of course, if you're going to distinguish between bottoms, the number of implementations becomes infinite as you can always create another error to raise. At some point, you have to declare that you've covered the cases you care about.
When you look at the 21 different functions you get from combining those cases together, you see that they overlap with id and foo (from above), so let's start counting fresh with those 21. The cases not covered are the cases when the argument is ignored, so we get a couple more:
bar22 :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
bar22 = undefined

bar23 :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
bar23 _ = Nothing

bar24 :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
bar24 _ = Just undefined

The _ -> undefined case is actually the same as the Nothing -> undefined ; Just x -> undefined case when you're not distinguishing bottoms, so it's already covered. Additionally, the bar22 case is special - moving the bottom out of the lambda actually can be distinguished from the rest of the cases at run time, thanks to seq.
So by my count, that's 24 functions with the type Maybe a -> Maybe a that can be distinguished by their behavior at runtime, ignoring execution time and the differences between bottoms. I know what Bird was trying to get at, but I find his choice of example very poor. Six is just not accurate due to nested non-strict values in both the argument and the result.
And if you're actually trying to use Haskell, you should see Maybe a -> Maybe a and assume that it only has two common implementations. The usual case for a function with non-recursive inputs and outputs is that you only care what outputs it creates without bottoms for inputs without bottoms. Everything else is a special case for particular contexts that need special treatment.

If we're gradually adding features to the language, it's possible to add undefined without adding seq.
